# Python How to run scripts from a subdirectory?

Tags: python, directory, python-import, relative-import

I have such structure of project:

```
lib/
    ...
scripts/
    ...
```

I have many Python scripts in the `scripts/` directory. All of them contains relative imports: `from lib import ...`

So, how can I easy run scripts from the root of project `/`, without changing scripts (without write `chdir` in each script)?

Maybe can I use some `__init__` file to change work dir? Or maybe can I use special command to run python scripts with root folder? Any other ways?

Comment: When you write `from lib import ...` this is an _absolute_ import and not a relative import. How exactly are you running your scripts and what exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `chdir` except if you have a *very* good reason. Add init files as detailed in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75138335/281545) and run your script from the parent directory (say root) as

```
$ python -m scripts.yourscript # note no .py
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me and its to much for a comment... Your structure is like that?

```
root/
├── lib/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib_foo.py
│   ├── lib_bar.py
├── scripts/
│   ├── script_util.py
│   └── script_yeah.py
└── main.py
```

And your program starts always at main.py? Or do you have python files with *main* also in the `scripts` folder ?

Comment: Yes, such structure. Main program only in main.py

Answer (score 0):

If you must run the scripts from their own directory and not use the suggestion from Mr_and_Mrs_D, then the simplest way to handle your use case is to manipulate the search path for the default module finder:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('..')
from lib import foo
sys.path.pop()

print(foo.bar())
```

It was a decision in Python to prevent explicitly loading a module from a relative folder above the executing process root. You can do it by creating a new 'finder' for importlib that returns a ModuleSpec, but the amount of code needed is somewhat excessive.